# Bukkit /seen command

Tags: bukkit

I was wondering how to make a seen command like in [Essentials](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/essentials/). I've tried many things, yet I still am not able to get it to work.

How can I add a `/seen` command to my Bukkit plugin?

Comment: Dont ask us to write a whole program for you... Ask specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy, straightforward ,cut and dry answer to this question. You will need to determine exactly what /seen does and will then have to code it all yourself. You will need to add an event handler to handle player Join/Quit and save the date/time of that event in a database with the players UUID and other info (such as name). Then you would need a second handler to handle a custom command called /seen, where you will need to lop through the database and find matching records and return information.

Answer (score 1):

Use a database where it keeps the players UUID stored and the time he logged in last

Answer (score 1):

Having a `/seen` command like essentials would be very complex. There is not really a simple way to do this.

One way to do it would be to store players into a `configuration file` or `hashmap`. I would recommend to not use `hashmaps` because when the server is restarted it will not save the data. When a player joins you can add them to an onlinelist of players and remove them from the offline list of players. When a player quits do the opposite. I know that if you have a certain permission for the `/seen` command you can see their IP address. Just use the method `getAddress()` from the player. To store their time online/offline you can add a timer and store that in config also as well as their string name. Do not store the entire player, just their name or UUID. I would recommend using UUID's because Essentials uses this way and since in 1.8 now you can change your name, nothing will get confusing. You can then loop through both of the online/offline lists to find the player a user enters in upon `/seen` and display their status offline if they are on the offline list, and online if they are on the online list.

This is just an idea to do it, you will have to code it yourself. This is just an idea for you to do this. I do not know exactly how Essentials does it, but you can look at their [GitHub page](https://github.com/essentials/Essentials/blob/2.x/Essentials/src/com/earth2me/essentials/commands/Commandseen.java) for information on how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

Prior warning, some of the data types I have used do not exist, you will need to replace them with the actual ones because I cannot remember all of them (e.g. Date)

Seen as I have no code to go off I will make my own up. Firstly you will need a way to save/load a .dat file in your Plugin directory, this will need an object output stream and object input stream.

Next you will need to create a hashmap that holds a UUID and a Date e.g.

```
HashMap lastSeen = new HashMap(UUID, Date);
```

You will want to handle a Player leaving event

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerLeave(PlayerDisconnectEvent e) { // PlayerDisconnectEvent not correct syntax

Date currentDate = system.getDate();
UUID p = e.getPlayer().getUUID();

if (lastSeen.contains(p)) { // Check if the player is already in the HashMap
    lastSeen.replace(p, currentDate); // Again replace isn't correct sytax
    return;
    }
lastSeen.add(p, currentDate);
}
```

Now you need in your onDisable and onEnable something like this

```
@Override
public void onDisable() {
    save(lastSeen, f); // f is the file you are saving to
}

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    lastSeen = load(f);
}
```

You will need some sort of function for save/load that contains an input/output stream to a set .dat file. Here is a helpful link for that: https://bukkit.org/threads/saving-loading-hashmap.56447/

Finally you will need to register the command and create a commandexecutor for the /seen command, that is fairly simple. All you would need to do then is check the entered players name in the /seen command, and get the respective hashmap date.

Answer (score 0):

[Look at the Essentials GitHub repository](https://github.com/essentials/Essentials/blob/2.x/Essentials/src/com/earth2me/essentials/commands/Commandseen.java). You can find the command for it there, but it is rather big, and includes a lot of code that is specific to Essentials (8 of the imports on the file are Essentials-specific), such as nicknames and checks for jailed & AFK. You will have to use what's there and adapt it to your plugin.

Comment: Yes, already did but you need alot of code and its complicated. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you maybe give us some code that you've tried to adapt and use and you edit it in, we could perhaps try and help you fix it up. Are there any errors when you're coding it?

Comment: The Essentials code will have tons of its own imports, and the class itself extends an Essentials-specific thing. You can't just 'try' another plugin's code. I'm not sure you understand how the code actually works - I think you need to learn how to code this sort of stuff first instead of trying to just copy-paste code like that.

Comment: If you won't post your code, we can't help. You're not giving us enough information either. We at least need the code you're using and errors will help a lot too.

Comment: At least the code you're using for the command, all the code would be even better.

Comment: Im not using any atm thats why i need your help. Cos i gave up trying stuff

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use an API to have multiple config files. Once I've got that, I would create a config file on startup called playerdata.yml to store the player's uuid. Then register a player join event and once the player joins, get it's uuid and name. Set the key `uuid + ".name"` to the value `name` (both uuid and name are variables storing the information received about the player) Also have a second file called playeruuids.yml and save the data `uuid` to the key `name` so that it will work while the player is offline. Then in the playerdata.yml file, get the current time in milliseconds and save it to the key `uuid + ".time"`. Save their IP to `uuid + ".ip"` too. Register a player leave event too and this time, save the current time in milliseconds to the same key, `uuid + ".time"`.

When a player runs /seen , get the name and check if the player is online or offline. If the player is online, you get their IP from the playerdata.yml file and display it along with their name. You can use SimpleDateFormat to convert the millisecond time to whatever format you want. Hours, minutes and seconds, just seconds, etc. to display that too. If the player is offline, you first check the playeruuids.yml file for their uuid using the provided name. If the resulting string is "", just display to the player that the specified player has never joined. Otherwise, use that uuid and the provided name to do the same as an online player. If you want, you could display "Online since:" or "Offline since:" before the time too.

Because your question is not very specific and can be answered in many ways, you will have to code this all yourself. Unless you have code that you have tried, you won't get any code because people use this website to get free code often rather than for it's purpose so just try to create something using the ideas provided for you and you can ask another question in the future once you actually have code that you have tried and will continue to try and work on, on your own to make it work.